# Efficient use of Run Application dialog

Tags: gnome-do, synapse

In Windows 7, there appeared this beautiful search/run field: You press Win, you start typing the program name, as soon as Windows correctly guesses it, you press Enter, and you're done.

In Ubuntu, Run Application is a somewhat similar thing. You press Alt+F2, you start typing the command or the application name, Ubuntu correctly guesses it (puts it on top of the list of known applications)... However at this point you cannot just press Enter. You have to use a mouse or press Tab 5 times.

Is there a way around?

Comment: Well, I am confused now.Is your question about Alt+F2 thing , or gnome-do and synapse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [**Synapse**](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project):

> Synapse is a semantic launcher written in Vala that you can use to start applications as well as find and access relevant documents and files by making use of the Zeitgeist engine.

[image]

**Features**:

> - Applications – searches your desktop files
>
>   - Banshee – allows you to play/enqueue music files in Banshee
>   - Commands – runs any command (ie. “sudo apt-get update”)
>   - Devhelp – search documentation using Devhelp
>   - Dictionary – find definitions of words
>   - Directory search – allows opening of commonly used directories
>   - Gnome session – log out, shut down, restart
>   - Hybrid search – complete Zeitgeist results by searching for similar files
>   - Rhytmbox – play/enqueue music files in Rhythmbox
>   - UPower – suspend & hibernate your computer
>   - Zeitgeist – search anything logged by Zeitgeist

**With a keyboard shortcut you can launch it and start searching for whatever you want :**

[image]

See for more info : [OMG! UBUNTU!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu/)

Comment: I have problems with it on Ubuntu MATE 16.04 beta 2. It can't find _Calculator_ application.

Answer (score 1):

If you start the dash with the superbutton, you have exactly the behaviour you wished. If you hit enter it will start the first program. So as long as you type enough letters to specify exactly the program you want to open you are done. BTW Thanks I didnt knew this behaviour before.

Comment: I think this is something from Unity. I'm still working with the Classic Gnome interface.